# vagrant supressing non-zero exit staus for shell provisioner

Tags: shell, vagrant, apt-get

I'm having a script provisioner in vagrant. My box is ubuntu 64bit Precise. The relevant lines of my script look like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb https://oss.oracle.com/debian/ unstable main non-free" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle.list'
wget -q https://oss.oracle.com/el4/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update -qq
```

The error code is:

```
W: GPG error: https://oss.oracle.com unstable Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1378511808 KEYEXPIRED 1378511808 KEYEXPIRED 1378511808
W: Failed to fetch https://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  The requested URL returned error: 404

W: Failed to fetch https://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  The requested URL returned error: 404

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
```

The problem is that despite I know that the repo has expired keys and is not for 64bit architecture (32bit only). Still I'd like to install relevant packages from it (which is possible, using: `<package_name>:i386`).
However during update due to non-exit status vagrant stops and doesn't continue my script any more.

Is there a way (either of vagrant or on the `apt-get` side) to make vagrant happy and continue execution of my script?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can force the error status to *zero* using `; true`:

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get update -qq ; true"
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Still had to use `|` instead of `;`. See the updated answer.

Comment: because with `;` vagrant will detect the non-zero status => will fail again. However with `|` vagrant has to execute all the commands in one shot => no chance to detect exit status of the command not at the end of chain. That's why. Please note, that if you keep the answer as it it now. It's incorrect.

Comment: @PeterButkovic: Can you please check this: `sudo sh -c 'apt-get update -qq ; true'`? The point is that you cover the command with non-zero exit code with shell; vargrant sees nothing suspicious. And that with the `| true` is wrong, because you lose the stdout of the command before the pipe.

Comment: I would love to know how this is done on a Windows host.

Comment: @BenJohnson: there are several methods: `ver > nul` or `cmd /c "exit /b 0"` or `set "errorlevel="`. Try them

Answer (score 4):

A slightly simpler approach than Igor's suggestion is to make it a boolean statement:

```
apt-get update -qq || true
```

This avoids invoking an unnecessary subshell.